# In Shell Scripting Array of folders in directory and show files in each folder, rename/delete option

Tags: linux, shell

Shell Scripting:
Array of folders in directory and show files in each folder, rename/delete option

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You haven't actually asked a question here. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on creating questions. In particular, it needs to include the code for your attempt to solve your problem. We are not short order programmers working for free, we are a community of people helping each other improve our craft. You can [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41561060/edit) to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is simple example using array of folders. You can add additional logic which you need.

```
#!/bin/bash
FOLDER=(`ls -d /home/*/`)
number=`ls -d /home/*/ | wc -l`
a=0
while [ $a -ne $number ]
do
echo ${FOLDER[a]}
a=$(expr $a + 1)
done
```

Comment: in each folder  ${FOLDER[a]}  , I have one file which i need to rename and move it to the other folder

Comment: You can modify my while loop according to your logic.

Comment: I am very new to shell script

Comment: while [ $a -ne $number ]
do
echo ${FOLDER[a]}
cd ${FOLDER[a]}
ls
a=$(expr $a + 1)
done

Comment: ls is doing listing , but i want to store this file name to one variable so that i can move this file to some other location

Comment: i=0
FOLDER=(`ls -d ${WORKSPACE}/publish/xyz/*/`)
number=`ls -d ${WORKSPACE}/publish/xyz/*/ | wc -l`
a=0
while [ $a -ne $number ]
do
echo ${FOLDER[a]}
cd ${FOLDER[a]}
ls

for var in *
do
if [ -f "$var" ]
then 
echo $var
YY="abc-PGT$i"
i=$((i+1))
newname=${ARTIFACTID}-${VERSION}.json
echo "============= $var =========== $newname"
mkdir -p ${WORKSPACE}/publish/rel13/${HH}/${YY}
mv $var  ${WORKSPACE}/publish/rel13/${HH}/${YY}/$newname
echo $var
#cp "$var" ${WORKSPACE}/publish/rel13/${YY}
fi
done
a=$(expr $a + 1)
done

Comment: Excelent. I hope my example helped for you.